# emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value)) vs emplace(std::make_pair(key, value))

Tags: c++

Two ways of emplacing:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m;
```

First: emplace moved key and value

```
// 1.
{
    std::string k1 = "key1";
    std::string v1 = "value1";
    m.emplace(std::move(k1), std::move(v1));
}
```

Second: emplace with pair made my `std::make_pair`:

```
// 2.
{
    std::string k2 = "key2";
    std::string v2 = "value2";
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(k2, v2));
}
```

Which is better (meaning more speed efficient)?

Comment: Note that 2. is roughly equivalent to `m.insert(std::make_pair(k2, v2));` as `insert` is overloaded to accept an r-value reference.

Comment: They are semantically different. The first one may leave `k1` and `k2` invalid. You should not rely on their values after `std::move`. The second one will anyway leave them valid, as they are lvalues and argument types of `std::make_pair` will be resolved to `std::string&`. The reason is that `std::make_pair` accepts so-called [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), i.e. rvalue references in a type-deduction context.

Comment: I think whether the strings `k1` and `v1` are moved or not is a distraction from what would otherwise be a good question. In both cases you can choose to move the strings or not (and with the SSO it will make little difference to performance). I think it would be clearer to compare like-with-like.

Answer (score 2):

> Which is better?

Better how? They're not equivalent.

Example 1 invokes the move constructor for `k1` and `v1`, leaving them in a valid but different state, their contents will have been moved away. If you intend on using `k1` or `v1` afterwards then there's no option and you should use #2. If you don't, then you should also move in #2 to avoid a copy:

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair(std::move(k2), std::move(v2)));
```

---

Which then leaves it up to readability:

```
m.emplace(std::move(k1), std::move(k2));
```

This calls `std::pair`'s template constructor to construct a `std::pair` from 2 rvalue refs.

**vs.**

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair(std::move(k2), std::move(v2)));
```

This calls `std::pair`'s move constructor since it's an rvalue.

If by "*Which is better?*" you mean performance then there's only 1 way to find out, which is benchmarking. Though I think `m.emplace(std::move(k1), std::move(k2));` has a slight edge. (as noted in the comments, because it avoids a conversion from non-const to const)

---

Main point, don't sweat it, both of them will be really efficient as all of it is moving. Pick the one that you think is more readable.

Comment: What slight edge?

Comment: But with `make_pair` there is also a conversion from `pair<string,string>` to `pair<const string,string>`. It might again be different if you use `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::value_type` constructor instead of `make_pair`.

Comment: j6t You are right. std::pair<const string, string> should avoid additional construction.

Comment: @j6t You are definitely right, I copied in the wrong one when talking about slight edge. Revised, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second option requires additional move/copy operations, what is not good. The first option works faster because there is no explicit pair creation. Actually, insertion and emplacement with explicit  creation of `std::pair` gives you the same speed.
I have tested. The option with `std::make_pair` requires 3 calls of move constructor for key/value, the option with `std::move` requires only 1 call of move constructor.
The example without and with /Ox optimization. msvc-2012

```
class C
{
    public:
    C()
    {
       std::cout << "C()" << std::endl;
    }

    C( const C& c )
    {
       std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }

    C( C&& c )
    {
       std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, C> c1;

    std::cout << "---Test Move---" << std::endl;
    C test1;
    c1.emplace(1, std::move(test1));

    std::cout << "---Test std::make_pair---" << std::endl;
    C test2;
    c1.emplace(std::make_pair(2, test2) );

    std::cout << "---Test bare pair---" << std::endl;
    C test3;
    c1.emplace(std::pair<const int, C>(3, test3) );

    return 0;
}
```

---Test Move--- 
C() 
move 
---Test std::make_pair--- 
C() 
copy 
move 
move 
---Test bare pair--- 
C() 
copy 
move